# Create a copy of the database in same server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a copy of database in mysql using mysqldbcopy like :

```
mysqldbcopy --source=root:xxx@13.67.59.xxx --destination=root:xxx@13.67.59.xxx old_db:new_db
```

I am getting error saying cannot connect to the destination server (Error code 110). 
Source and destination is same server. I want to know which user and ip i need to put here, whether to put mysql username and password or server username and password. Please help me out in this.

Comment: why don't  we can use mysqldump for this? any issues? it would be simple to take backup using mysqldump -uuser dbname >backup.sql and then restore using mysql -uroot newdb <backup.sql

Comment: Could you add the exact error message? You might try `--source=root:pass@localhost:port` and actually use `localhost` instead of using the IP address.

Comment: *I am getting error saying cannot connect to the destination server (Error code 110).* `mysqldbcopy` allows to copy database locally without limitation. Maybe the source of Your problem is no multi-logon allowed? Try to create separate users for source and destination connections...

Comment: **13.67.59.xxx** is external host? If so, remember, all of data will be copied via Your workstation... if Db size is large, it may cause some problems, and in any case will take a long time. Maybe server-local copy process is more safe?

Answer (score 1):

do dump of your current database

mysqldump -p yourDatabase > file.sql

then create new database and restore file.sql

mysql -p -e "create database new_DB"

mysql -p new_DB < file.sql

Answer (score 0):

Same database just on different schema names? Try this:

`CREATE DATABASE new_db;
CREATE TABLE new_db.tbl_name AS SELECT * FROM old_db.tbl_name;`

If you have a bunch of tables in there you can just create a script to do the job.

Comment: I have so many functions, procs triggers and all. So cannot work out like that.

Comment: what exact errors are you getting from mysqldbcopy? maybe you need to specify the socket file

Comment: @Nikesh *many functions, procs* functions/procedures scope is server, not database.